# Context Menu not being displayed

Tags: android, android-contextmenu

Here is the section of my code in onCreate() Method:

```
LayoutX = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LL_SomeName);
LayoutX.setClickable(true);
registerForContextMenu(LayoutX);
```

Here is rest of the code

CreateContextMenu

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu M, View V, ContextMenuInfo CMI) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(M, V, CMI);
    M.setHeaderTitle("My Title Here");
    M.add(0, V.getId(), 0, "Menu 1");
    M.add(0, V.getId(), 0, "Menu 2");
}
```

ItemSelected

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem Item) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

The Context Menu does not appear at all. Am I missing anything ?

Comment: I have an OptionsMenu on the same Activity as well. Is there a possible conflict ?

Comment: are you `long-pressing` `LayoutX` or are you just clicking?

Comment: dude, see [this example](http://moorandroid.blogspot.in/p/context-menu.html); it has the source code downloadable option too:)

Comment: @vikki Thanks. I was making the mistake of not long clicking it.

Answer (score 0):

this may help  you

```
  @Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Select one");
        menu.add(0, 1, 0, "Edit");
        menu.add(0, 2, 0, "Delete");
    }

   public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(item.getItemId()==1){
      // edit option is selected
     }
```

Comment: How is that supposed to help me. There is nothing new / changed in there. Just some variables renamed. Flag the answer down.